# Selenium C# how to select an element on a dynamic li id list within a class

Tags: c#, dynamic-data, selenium-webdriver

```
<ul class="cartItems">
  <li id="ba464302-4733-4a06-80af-44e315d98bc9" class="cartItem">
      <div class="thumbContainer">
           <span class="transferLinks">
     <a href="javascript:;" class="saveForLater">Save for later </a>

  <li id="199e3fff-f80c-4df4-a4ff-26edd804ee5c" class="cartItem">
  <div class="thumbContainer">
           <span class="transferLinks">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="saveForLater">Save for later </a>
```

I am trying to choose all the element individually of "saveForLater" class located within a dynamic  "li id" list (for example:  0F347571a5-406c-49da-ac1f-37cf9aa2628b) that's within a "ul class", "cartItems" in the enclosed code.  I have tried the following code

1. `IWebElement cartItemByXpath = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='cartItems']/li"));`
2. `IWebElement cartItems = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".cartItems .cartItem .actionLinks .saveForLater"));`

Line 1 above only return all the text under `cartItems`, not the "li id" that I was looking for
Line 2 above will select `saveForLater` class, but I still need to get to the rest of the `saveForLater` class under other "li id" on the list.
"li id" is dynamic and changes in value.     Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Driver.FindElements` to get all matching elements list, then loop through the list for your need.

```
IList<IWebElement> cartItems = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".cartItems .cartItem .actionLinks .saveForLater"));

foreach (IWebElement cartItem in cartItems ) {
//your action on individual "cartItem"

}
```

Hope this helps...